# Prove that for every exponent $e\ge 1$, the congruence $x^2+1\equiv 0$ (mod $5^e$) has a solution $x_e\in \mathbb{Z}/5^e\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory

Prove that for every exponent $e\ge 1$, the congruence $x^2+1\equiv 0$ (mod $5^e$) has a solution $x_e\in \mathbb{Z}/5^e\mathbb{Z}$. Prove further that these solutions can be chosen to satisfy $x_1\equiv 2$ (mod 5), and $x_{e+1}\equiv x_e$ (mod $5^e$) for all $e \ge 1$.

This is my solution thus far.

If $e=1$ then the solutions are $x=2,3$ and so the base case holds. Now assume that the statement holds for some $e> 1$. Then we have that for some $m,j\in\mathbb{N}$ $$(5^em+x_e)^2+1=5^2em^2+2x_e5^em+x_e^2+1=5^e(5^em^2+2x_em+j)$$

I am having trouble showing that the last expression above is congruent to $0$ modulo $5^{e+1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing is that you seem to have a slight misunderstanding.  You don't have to prove that your expression is **always** congruent to $0$, you have to prove that **for some value of $m$** it is congruent to $0$.  So, modulo $5^{e+1}$ we have
$$\eqalign{(5^em+x_e)^2+1
  &\equiv5^{2e}m^2+2x_e5^em+x_e^2+1\cr
  &\equiv5^{e+1}5^{e-1}m^2+2x_e5^em+j5^e\cr
  &\equiv(2x_em+j)5^e\ .\cr}$$
Now it is easy to see that $x_e$ is not a multiple of $5$.  Therefore you can choose $m$ such that
$$2x_em\equiv-j\pmod5\ ,$$
and then $(5^em+x_e)^2+1$ is a multiple of $5^{e+1}$, as required.

If you want a specific solution, $m=2jx_e^3$ will do.